# I want to send input value to the other page in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, dom

I want to send input value to the to the other page in **node.js**.I am working on a travel agency project.So i have a buy ticket page and the page that shows your ticket including your name,surname etc.
So i want to take client's name from my input and i want to send that to ticket page and the ticket will shown client's name.I have a js file which i included that both to buy ticket and ticket page.I wrote a function for test.The function is when you click the buy ticket button in the "buy ticket" page,it will do document.write("Hi there"); Like that:

```
<button onlcick="buy()">Buy</button>
```

Js:

```
function buy() {
document.write("Ticket bought");
}
```

It worked when i click the buy button in the "buy ticket" page it writes "Ticket Bought" in the "ticket" page.Now i want to send the input value which that input including client's name,and i want to show the name on the ticket.
My code

```
 <form class="row g-3 needs-validation" style="margin-top: 50px;" action="/ticket" method="POST" novalidate>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="validationCustom01" class="form-label" style="color: white;">First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" value="" required>
            <div class="valid-feedback">
              Looks good!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="validationCustom01" class="form-label" style="color: white;">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" value="" required>
            <div class="valid-feedback">
              Looks good!
            </div>
          </div>
<button type="submit" onclick="buy">Buy</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var user_name,user_surname;
user_name = document.getElementById("name")
user_surname = document.getElementById("surname");
function buy(){
  var surnameValue,nameValue;
  nameValue = user_name.value;
  surnameValue = user_surname.value;
  document.write(nameValue + surnameValue);
}
```

I want that the code will write the user's name and surname but i get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

How can i solve that?
P.S:I have a controller.js and router.js file which control the localhost path.

Comment: why not pass parameters in a `URL query component`, e.g. `foo.com?name=joe` or you could pass values in a HTML POST message.

Comment: I can't because i am posting the site.

Comment: do your `document.getElementById` inside the `buy()` function.

Comment: it could be an asynchronous issue. move those top 3 line of JS into the body of the `buy()`

Comment: you mean i should write user_name and user_surname as a parameter of the buy function? I will do that